# Best way to store product colors in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on an online jewelry store website. One of the requests is that from the back end a color/colors can be chosen for a single piece of jewelry so that users would be able to sort/view only items that are for instance green.

What is the best way to store this in a database? Should this be done with 3 tables:

1. product table (already exists)
2. color table : each field has a color
3. table that matches the product is with the color id

Is this the correct way to do it? I am using php and mysql but I think this is just a pretty standard database question.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: IMHO, since colors (solid colors) are limited and known, `color` should be an attribute of `product`. Having the option of adding colors at will will cause problems, like having 20+ tones for purple (purple, fuchsia, eggplant, etc.) and making simple queries become complex.

Comment: @Ben I don't really agree with that. Having a standard N-M relationship is not going complicate the query that much

Comment: @Marcus I don't say it because the n-m relationship, I say it because let's say you want to list all the purple diamonds, how can you know that fuschia and eggplant are also purple?

Comment: @Ben Ah, that way around. But then you could limit the colors in the Color table aswell to achieve the same goal. Alternative make groups the colors belongs to if there are to be a lot of different flavors.

Comment: If I were to just make it an attribute of the product, I would only be able to choose 1 color per product no? Some product have multiple colors like black and white so they will be displayed in both scenarios.

Comment: @Sackling Didn't mentioned items could have more than one color. In that case a relationship table is mandatory.

Comment: @Ben Yea sorry about that was not clear. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution with a many-to-many relationship between tables sounds good for your case. You can then easily JOIN the tables to get information out of the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's an appropriate way to do it.