# Whats the best way to design a database with a product of multiple variations?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

This question is related to this one: [Best way to store product colors in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126875/best-way-to-store-product-colors-in-a-database)

So i have a Product which have the multiple properties. Below is an illustration.

Product A

```
Name: Product A v1.0, Product A v2.0 (2 versions of Product A)
Color: Black, White, Blue
Capacity: 16MB, 32MB, 64MB
Carrier: T-Mobile, Digicel, Vonage
```

This product can only have one of each property. Ex: a Black 32MB, Vonage product A v2.0

I am unsure of how to setup this product in a normalized database. Do I create separate tables for Product Name, Color, Capacity and Carrier.. and then create a linking table between Product A v1.0 and Color, Product A v1.0 and Capacity, Product A v1.0 and Carrier and so on?

I am also unsure because, Product A v1.0 only offers 16MB Black/White, while v2.0 offers all colors, all capacities and only one cellular carrier. And i could go on with other minor variations.

Comment: Must it have one of each property? Could you have a product without a carrier for instance?

Comment: Why not have a column for each, and a value in there. Name is probably   a varchar, color you could just store the color as text (or have a separate table that maps to an int - probably overkill imo), capacity store as an int, and carrier probably use a CarrierId that links to another table of Carriers (so you can add more about a carrier)

Comment: @corsiKa no, Product A v1.0 for instance does not support vonage carrier.

Comment: @Prescott you mean have a column for each like this?
-------------------
name|color|carrier|capacity|

etc?

Comment: Yeah, why not? That's 4 columns, maybe 5 if you add a surrogate primary key (like an auto incremented int). If they only have one value for each, then that will be fine. If they could have multiple values (like Product A could be on carrier T-Mobile and Digicel), they you want to talk about another table similar to Dan's answer

Comment: @Prescott ok maybe i confused you a bit. A customer can choose Product A with T-mobile and another customer can also chose Product A with Digicel. So i'm guessing i'll look into Dan's answer some more.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry, Dans answer all the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how I would link product and colors in Oracle (updated to show how you can create a primary key on products with a separate unique key):

```
CREATE TABLE product_color (
    color_name VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT color_pk PRIMARY KEY (color_name)
);

CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id NUMBER,
    product_name VARCHAR2(100),
    color_name VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
    CONSTRAINT color_fk FOREIGN KEY (color_name) 
        REFERENCES product_color (color_name),
    CONSTRAINT product_uk UNIQUE (product_name, color_name)
);
```

This basically creates a foreign key to a value table.  If you try to insert a color or invalid text not in the product_color table, the constraint will prevent it.

Now, I could have normalized this further and associated an integer key with each color, and created a foreign key to the integer.  However, this type of normalization will lead to a lot of joins in your SQL statements, particularly when you start adding additional attributes.  I find this way to be a good compromise with cleaner SQL.

Comment: +1 for saying don't use surrogate keys where they're not needed.

Comment: @Ben, I've maintained applications that go completely overboard with the surrogate keys.  After trying to maintain SQL statements with 20 or 30 joins, I've learned to appreciate the beauty of simplicity.  :)

Comment: Ok I understand, I can create a Product table, and then add Color, capacity, and carrier to the table as foreign keys. So the table will end up having: product_name(pk), color(fk), capacity(fk), carrier(fk). Sounds good BUT, if the product_name is the primary key, how can i have the following 2 variations in the Product table? : (1) productA, 16MB, Black, T-mobile ** (2) productA, 32MB, Black, T-mobile.. ?

Comment: @user76859403 You can create a composite primary key on all of the fields that uniquely identify a product in your table.  So maybe PRIMARY KEY (product_name, color, capacity, carrier).

Comment: On the other hand, it may be easier to create an auto-incrementing primary key so you have an easier way to pull a product from the database without having to pass in multiple fields.  Then, to prevent duplicate products, create a separate composite UNIQUE key on all of those fields.

Comment: You're welcome!  I've updated my answer to show you an example of a primary key with a separate unique key.

Comment: the only issue  about this response is: i will have many variation primary keys... like.. very many. I only showed you guys color, capacity, and carrier.. but there are many other varying factors that will result in many primary keys. I wish there was a simpler way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9248/discussion-between-dan-a-and-user76859403)